# Heroku doesn't recognize DATABASE_URL

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I've deployed my site to heroku and now I'm trying to push my local database up but keep getting this error:

> ▸ Unknown database:
>
> ▸  *my_database_url*
>
> ▸  Valid options are: DATABASE_URL

After using the command:

> heroku pg:push postgres://user@localhost:5432/*app_name*
> *heroku_database_url*    --app   *heroku_app_name*

But the DATABASE_URL I'm using is the one that I've gotten from heroku with

> heroku config:get DATABASE_URL

and using the returned value. I tried reseting the DATABASE_URL but I still get the same error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm having a similar issue; when I GET request to the postgres  database it returns an ssl error. The weird part is that when I console.log the DATABASE_URL it's undefined. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

**Solved**: Needed to use the literal word "DATABASE_URL" instead of the string returned from Heroku when asked for the DATABASE_URL